# Erase area from GeoTIFF covered by area in another GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have 2 GeoTIFFs, A and B and I want to produce GeoTIFF C:

- Both A and B have 4 bands (RGBA) and the same projection
- A covers large area and has lower resolution (bigger pixel size) than B
- B covers smaller area, all within area of A
- B has nodata areas

I would like to produce C which would be the same as A but with all the areas that are in B as non-nodata (ie. has data) to be set to fully transparent (band 4 and optionally all other bands to zero).

In other words I want to produce C = A - B where the "hole" created by B would be RGBA=0,0,0,0.

I need to do it on Linux (GDAL, QGIS, ...). Note that both files are pretty big (A - 56GB, B - 295GB).

Any ideas? As a last resort I would maybe use gdal_calc but I am not sure how would it handle different pixel sizes.